# Spark scala- How to apply transformation logic on a generic set of columns defined in a file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am using spark scala 1.6 version.
I have 2 files, one is a schema file which has hundreds of columns separated by commas and another file is .gz file which contains data.
I am trying to read the data using the schema file and apply different transformation logic on a set of few columns .
I tried running a sample code but I have hardcoded the columns numbers in the attached pic.
Also I want to write a udf which could read any set of columns and apply the transformation like replacing a special character and give the output.
Appreciate any suggestion

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

```
  val rdd1 = sc.textFile("../inp2.txt")

  val rdd2 = rdd1.map(line => line.split("\t"))
  val rdd2 = rdd1.map(line => line.split("\t")(1)).toDF

  val replaceUDF = udf{s: String => s.replace(".", "")}

  rdd2.withColumn("replace", replaceUDF('_1)).show
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the field name file with simple scala code and create a list of column names as

```
  // this reads the file and creates a list of columnnames 
  val line  = Source.fromFile("path to file").getLines().toList.head
  val columnNames = line.split(",")

  //read the text file as an rdd and convert to Dataframe
  val rdd1 = sc.textFile("../inp2.txt")
  val rdd2 = rdd1.map(line => line.split("\t")(1))
      .toDF(columnNames : _*)
```

This creates a dataframe with columns names that you have in a separate file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did that helped you ?

Comment: Hi Shankar, thanks for your answer. I am getting an error now . I have attached the screenshot of the error. Please advise

Comment: Sorry Not sure how to attach an image here in comment

Comment: You can upload somewhere and send the link